# Sendgrid as a service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, sendgrid

Is it possible to use Sendgrid on Bluemix as a service from an external app (non Bluemix app). When I created the service, it just allows me to go to Sendgrid dashboard. I am looking to be able to invoke Sendgrid from an external mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an API key from your Sendgrid Dashboard in Bluemix and use it to connect to the service from everywhere. I've just tried it using an external Java application running on my machine and it works. Please take a look at the [Sendgrid integration Docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html). There you can find the clients for the main programming languages and also a Web API that you can use:

- If you choose to use SendGrid without a client library.
- If your ISP blocks all outbound mail ports and your only option is HTTP.
- If you do not control the application environment and cannot install and configure an SMTP library.
- If you build a library to send email (developing against a web API provides quicker development).